# Ubuntu screen turned OFF during ddrescue operation

Tags: screen, ddrescue

I was recovering some files from my failing hardrive using ddrescue tool.
I went for little walk ,when I came back I saw screen is black with screen backlight ON , KEYBOARD BACKLIT is also ON.I pressed some keys but nothing.I waited for 2hours for it to be resumed but it's still blank.

What to do now?
Should I force shout down laptop?
I was using a logfile, so will I be able to resume the ddrescue operation?
Will shutdown going to have bad impact on hardrive?

Should I wait more?
Link to the image of my laptop in current situation:
https://ibb.co/bK9GqjQ

Comment: I have seen GNOME Shell get wedged like this before. One way I have found to work around it is press `CTRL+ALT+F1` to switch to another console, then `CTRL+ALT+F2` to switch back to the desktop. (it's F2 for me, might be F7 or some other, but I don't know because you didn't mention Ubuntu version).

Comment: I tried the keys but nothing happening. I was just using ddrescue and went for walk for 3minutes ,what happened meanwhile K don't know.

Comment: https://ibb.co/bK9GqjQ
 Image of the laptop

Comment: Just in case you end up deciding for a forced reboot, look up the "REISUB" method. If it's effective, it's way more delicate on the system.

Comment: Does the caps-lock button function (i.e. does it light up when pressed) ? If not then it's likely the kernel has hard locked-up and a reboot is really your only exit.

Comment: Yeah caps lock is working, I did the force shutdown and then resumed ddrescue ,it seems working fine